# PHP outputs mysqli row values outside while loop

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to output row values outside while loop for this

```
$sql = mysqli_query($connection, "select username from accounts where rank='admin'");

         while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {

           $username = $row['username'];

         }
```

I would like to output and print the result outside the while loop.
I Tried `print_r` but it doesn't seem to work, it only shows the last or first value but not all.

Answer (score 3):

You need to save each value in an array inside of the `while` loop.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
  //save in array
  $username[] = $row['username'];
}

//output values
print_r($username);
```

You need the brackets `[]` to save each value into the array. `$username[]`